# The choice of method for constructing hardware monitoring and diagnostics

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, programming, test

created a weight scale device.
I chose the software method for diagnosing my system. How can I implement it?

X1 is a load cell 5000 grams

DA2 [HX711](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/292970809/?*=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%3D&lang=en)

D1 [Atmeaga328](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/292970809/?*=9H4UxCNxZcpolVgF3ET1g%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%3D%3D&lang=en)

D2 [shift register](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/583/DOC001583313.pdf)

H1 lcd display

What is the best way to test these items before each run?

How to test the system every time before starting.

Comment: Hi, (a) Although you just edited the question to remove the schematic, I was going to mention that a quick check shows some problems with that circuit. If you have it working already, then the schematic does not accurately represent what is working. (b) IMHO you need to be clearer about what type of testing you want to include. Just one simple example - you would need additional components if you want to test whether the LCD backlight is working or not. Without a better specification of the testing required, especially with multiple devices, this question seems too broad.

Comment: What part of the system do you think you need to test and what possible failures could you detect?

Comment: As others will tell you, this is not a "how do I do something" site.  If you have a problem, you need to make an effort to solve it yourself, then ask specific questions pertaining to your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others will tell you, this is not a "how do I do something" site.  If you have a problem, you need to make an effort to solve it yourself, then ask specific questions pertaining to your proposed solution.

Comment: The question is posed for sure.
How to test such a system before starting?
For example, I can do it using the Hamming code. But I want to test it programmatically. How to test the device programmatically, so that if something happens an error will appear on the display.

Comment: @Steve While you are right, this should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You can help me.
How to test the system every time before starting.

Comment: @Lundin - You're right - I added a comment to the same as a comment.